# To get particular value from HTML text

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have a scenario where i need to fetch the value of patientIId from the text returned in the format of HTML.
When i query the below xpath
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//div[@name='DemographicsTab']//div[@class='control-xml'][contains(text(),'< view view="SAC.UIConfig.GenericFrameTabberInnerCo')]

I get the below text

```
 "<view view="SAC.UIConfig.GenericFrameTabberInnerContainer" 
    target-uri="DemographicsTab" 
    tab-appearance=" AbsoluteView TabContainer "
    appearance-class=" AbsoluteView TabContainer " title="">
    <argument local-name="PagePatientIID" value="10032" />
    <argument local-name="Patient" value="10032" />
    <argument local-name="PagePatientDemographicsIID" value="53" />
    <argument local-name="Node" value="DemographicsTab" />
    <argument local-name="CurrentFrame" value="ContentFrame" /><argument local-name="CurrentViewTargetName" value="DemographicsTab" />
    </view>"
```

*

Kindly help me in getting the value of "PagePatientDemographicsIID" from the above text.
i.e i need the **value = "53"**

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get what you need if you add the following to your X-Path: `/argument[@local-name="PagePatientDemographicsIID"]`.

This should yield the following node: `<argument local-name="PagePatientDemographicsIID" value="53" />`.

Comment: also `.getText()` wont give him 53 as it is in value attribute

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
To get value from text, you can use regex:

```
String tt = "<view view=\"SAC.UIConfig.GenericFrameTabberInnerContainer\" \n" +
        "    target-uri=\"DemographicsTab\" \n" +
        "    tab-appearance=\" AbsoluteView TabContainer \"\n" +
        "    appearance-class=\" AbsoluteView TabContainer \" title=\"\">\n" +
        "    <argument local-name=\"PagePatientIID\" value=\"10032\" />\n" +
        "    <argument local-name=\"Patient\" value=\"10032\" />\n" +
        "    <argument local-name=\"PagePatientDemographicsIID\" value=\"53\" />\n" +
        "    <argument local-name=\"Node\" value=\"DemographicsTab\" />\n" +
        "    <argument local-name=\"CurrentFrame\" value=\"ContentFrame\" /><argument local-name=\"CurrentViewTargetName\" value=\"DemographicsTab\" />\n" +
        "    </view>";
String pattern = "PagePatientDemographicsIID\"\\s+value=\"(.*)\"";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(tt);
System.out.println("PagePatientDemographicsIID value: " + m.group(1));
```

---

If there's only one element on the page:

```
String patientDemographicsIID = driver.findElement(By.id("PagePatientDemographicsIID")).getAttribute("value");
```

Get value if you know **PagePatientIID**:

```
String patientDemographicsIID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//view[@target-uri='DemographicsTab' and .//*[@value='10032']]//*[@local-name='PagePatientDemographicsIID']")).getAttribute("value");
```

Get all **PagePatientIID** if there're more than one:

```
driver.findElements(By.id("PagePatientDemographicsIID"))
                .forEach(patient -> System.out.println(patient.getAttribute("value")));
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value of *PagePatientDemographicsIID* i.e. **53** from the HTML you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("view[target-uri='DemographicsTab'][view$=GenericFrameTabberInnerContainer] argument[local-name=PagePatientDemographicsIID]"))).getAttribute("value"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//view[@target-uri='DemographicsTab' and contains(@view, 'GenericFrameTabberInnerContainer')]//argument[@local-name='PagePatientDemographicsIID']"))).getAttribute("value"));
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but getAttribute("value") is returning null.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//div[@name='DemographicsTab']//div[@class='control-xml'][contains(text(),'<view view="SAC.UIConfig.GenericFrameTabberInnerCo')]").getAttribute("innerText")  will give me below text
"<view view="SAC.UIConfig.GeericFraeTaberInnerContainer" target-uri="DemographicsTab" tab-appearance=" AbsoluteView TabContainer " appearance-class=" AbsoluteView TabContainer " title="><argument local-name="Patient" value="10040" /><argument local-name="PagePatientDemographicsIID" value="63" /><argument local-name="Node" value="DemographicsTab" /></view>"

Comment: @HemaLatha Can you cross check once in chrome-devtools if `By.cssSelector("view[target-uri='DemographicsTab'][view$=GenericFrameTabberInnerContainer] argument[local-name=PagePatientDemographicsIID]")` and `//view[@target-uri='DemographicsTab' and contains(@view, 'GenericFrameTabberInnerContainer')]//argument[@local-name='PagePatientDemographicsIID']` identifies the element uniquely?

Comment: Cross checked, its not identifying element, because "view[target-uri='DemographicsTab'][view$=GenericFrameTabberInnerContainer] argument[local-name=PagePatientDemographicsIID]"  is a text

Comment: @HemaLatha 95% chance the webelement is within an `<iframe>`, you need to switch to the iframe first